# How to show 'too few arguments' error when no sub command is specified for argparse in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

An example script:

```
import argparse

def main(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

    parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
    parser_a.add_argument('--foo', choices='ABC', help='foo help')

    parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
    parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')

    args = parser.parse_args(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With Python2:

```
$ python2 test.py
usage: PROG [-h] {a,b} ...
PROG: error: too few arguments
```

This is what I want, when missing sub command in command line, the script prompt an error of missing argument, and prompt me with a brief usage message.

But with Python3:

```
$ python3 test.py
# nothing happens
```

It doesn't prompt any help about the usage and exit silently (though I can use `python3 test.py -h` to get the help messages). How can I change the code to make it works like the python2 way and make it compatible for both Python2 and Python3?

So in Python2, it can detect missing sub command error and quit early, but not for Python3. The problem for me is I have many code after `parser.parse_args(args)` that relies on the parsed args, it works for python2, and I find this issue when migrate it to Python3, if no sub command is specified in command line, these code will raise error, I need a way to detect that there is sub command specified in command line, and should not break the script to run under python2.

One possible solution for me could be check whether the parsed 'args' is empty, but it doesn't work for me because my script has some global options like:

```
parser.add_argument('--go', choices='123', help='global option help')
```

Comment: Try renaming the program to something other than `test.py` just to save yourself headaches later. I see your Python 3 result on both 3.6.5 and 2.7.15.

Comment: I don't think the script name has anything to do with the results, and my testing under python3.6.6 and python2.7.15 show me different results as what I described in my question.

Comment: You're right, it won't, but it's not wise to shadow the names of standard library packages is all. I merely reported my own results as a data point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 3.7 docs the subcommands section, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands, includes

> - required - Whether or not a subcommand must be provided, by default False.

This is missing in earlier v3 versions, but you can use

```
subparsers.required = True
```

Also make sure you include a `dest='cmd'` (or your choice) so the error message can name the missing subparsers command.

Subparsers used to be required (since under the covers the argument is a positional which normally required).  But with a change in Py3 in how required arguments were tested and reported, subparsers fell through the cracks.  So Py3 subparsers have been not-required for some time.  Adding the `required` parameter gives you the option of fixing that (the default False is nod toward that awkward interim case).

```
In [525]:     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
     ...: 
     ...:     subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='
     ...: cmd')
     ...:     subparsers.required = True
     ...:     parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
     ...:     parser_a.add_argument('--foo', choices='ABC', help='foo help')
     ...: 
     ...:     parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
     ...:     parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')
     ...: 
     ...:     args = parser.parse_args([])
     ...: 
     ...: 
usage: PROG [-h] {a,b} ...
PROG: error: the following arguments are required: cmd
```